# How do i fit that sparql calculation?

Tags: syntax-error, sparql

this is my actual problem:
?var0 is a group variable and ?var1 is not. But whenever I try to validate the syntax, there comes the following error message:

```
Non-group key variable in SELECT: ?var1 in expression ( sum(?var0) / ?var1 )
```

The complete Query:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX cz: <http://www.vs.cs.hs-rm.de/ontostor/SVC#Cluster>
PREFIX n: <http://www.vs.cs.hs-rm.de/ontostor/SVC#Node>

SELECT ( (SUM(?var0) / ?var1) AS ?result)
WHERE{
    ?chain0 rdf:type rdfs:Property .
    ?chain0 rdfs:domain <http://www.vs.cs.hs-rm.de/ontostor/SVC#Cluster> .
    ?chain0 rdfs:range <http://www.vs.cs.hs-rm.de/ontostor/SVC#Node> .

    ?this ?chain0 ?arg0 .
    ?arg0 n:node_realtime_cpu ?var0 .
    ?this cz:node_count ?var1 .
}
```

My question is how to correct that calculation to fit the SPARQL syntax?

Comment: Please show the rest of the query.  If `?var1` isn't a group variable, then when you group by whatever variables you're grouping by, the group has a collection of values for `?var1` (one for each result in the group).  If you know for sure that they're all the same, then you could `sample(?var1)`, or you could group by `?var1` in addition to whatever else you're grouping by (`group by ... ?var1 ...`).  Otherwise, there could be a bunch of different values for `?var1` in the group, and you haven't specified how you want to aggregate them into one value to use in the computation.

Comment: If you can show the rest of your query, it will probably be much clearer what you're trying to do, and you'll get more helpful responses.  As it is now, there's not enough information to really tell what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that `?var1` is not grouped on, so a fix would be to simply append

`GROUP BY ?var1`

at the end of your query.

However, whether that gives you the calculation you actually want is another matter.

It's not quite clear what you're trying to calculate, but it looks as if you're attempting to determine the average `node_realtime_cpu` for a cluster. If that is the case, you can probably do your calculation by just using SPARQL's AVG function instead:

```
SELECT ( AVG(?var0) AS ?result)
WHERE{
    ?chain0 rdf:type rdfs:Property .
    ?chain0 rdfs:domain <http://www.vs.cs.hs-rm.de/ontostor/SVC#Cluster> .
    ?chain0 rdfs:range <http://www.vs.cs.hs-rm.de/ontostor/SVC#Node> .

    ?this ?chain0 ?arg0 .
    ?arg0 n:node_realtime_cpu ?var0 .
} 
GROUP BY ?this // grouping on the cluster identifier so we get an average _per cluster_
```

Yet another alternative would be to keep your query as-is, but group on two variables:

```
GROUP BY ?this ?var1
```

Which is best depends on what your data looks like and what, exactly, you're trying to calculate.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, it works now :)
I dont exactly know what there is to be calculated. I just have to translate some functions from XML to SPARQL so the priority is syntactical correctness ;)

Comment: Fair enough. By the way, if you feel my answer has helped you enough to solve the problem, you can indicate this by "accepting" the answer (the tick-mark underneath upvote-downvote buttons). See ["what should I do when someone answers"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Not required of course, but nice if you do :)